# How long to store slow-cooked chicken in liquid in fridge?

Tags: chicken, slow-cooking, storage-lifetime

I cooked some chicken in the slow cooker and stored the leftovers in the fridge. I put it all into a sealed tupperware container, but I put the chicken in with the liquid.

It just occurred to me that storing the chicken in liquid might have been a bad idea. It's been about 4 days now, is it still ok to eat? Does the liquid or the slow cooker change how long it could be stored for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it has been treated appropriately in all other ways (not being left out at in the "danger zone" of 40-140 F / 4-60 C for more than about two hours commulative over the entire life time, raw and cooked)) cooked chicken should last 3-4 days in the refrigerator.

See for example, the example of fried chicken [per South Carolina's Department of Health and Environmental Control](http://www.scdhec.gov/environment/envhealth/food/htm/fridge-shelf-life.htm).  It is the only example of cooked chicken in the list, but should be well representative.  Similarly, [Still Tasty](http://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/16776) advises 3-4 days on chicken broth, which would represent the juice or gravy—they indicate the same for chicken Parmesan.

You may be noticing a trend here: all chicken based dishes have about the same storage lifetime.

The fact that it is stored with the juice or gravy, or that you cooked it in a slow cooker is not really important.

Comment: That's good info. For some reason I just always assumed chicken went bad faster in liquid...I'm not sure where I got that from.  Thanks mate!